# Require cannot load such file bcrypt_ext loaderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

При запуске выскакивает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой Gemfile:

```js
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
 gem 'rack-cors'
 gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.7'
 gem 'devise_token_auth'
 gem 'omniauth'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.11'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end


group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'
  gem 'spring', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Замените в вопросе картинку сообшением как текст.

Comment: `bundle install` ни на что не пожаловался?